# sql query by field priority

Tags: sql, oracle

i have to do a query with oracle to find customers by some field priority
fields are :

```
    NUM_CIN,NUM_PASS,BIRTHDATE,NAME
```

the priority in the query are :

1) First by NUM_CIN if no result then

2) By NUM_PASS  if no result then

3) By NAME + Birthdate if no result

4) Only by NAME

how to do that with oracle sql please ?

Comment: You need more detailed explanation of what you are asking for, provide some sample data, and show what results you want based on that sample data.  My first thought is to use Analytics (use the row_number over () construct to order the rows in the priority you want, then pick off the first row .. whatever it is).

Answer (score 0):

you can union 4 queries with the 4 conditions and append a virtual column with priority. Something like this:

```
WITH all_results AS (

  SELECT t1.*, 
         1 priority
  FROM   CUSTOMER_TABLE t1
  WHERE  NUM_CIN = ... 

  UNION 

  SELECT t2.*,
         2 priority 
  FROM   CUSTOMER_TABLE t2
  WHERE  NUM_PASS = ...

  UNION 

  SELECT t3.*, 
         3 priority
  FROM   CUSTOMER_TABLE t3
  WHERE  NAME = ... AND BIRTHDATE = ...

  UNION 

  SELECT t4.*,
         4 priority
  FROM   CUSTOMER_TABLE t4
  WHERE  NAME = ...

)

SELECT *
FROM   all_results
WHERE  priority = (SELECT min(priority) FROM all_results)
```